# Broadcasting allocates a lot of memory whist for loop doesn't

Tags: memory-management, julia, broadcast

If I have following two variants to write a part of my code and I generally prefer a shorter one. This is the reason why I do like dot-broadcasting in Julia. However I have this example shows that there's something wrong with it.

```
function test1(A)
    n = size(A, 2)
    for k in 1:n
        for i in k+1:n
            A[i, k] /= A[k, k]
        end
    end
    A
end

function test2(A)
    n = size(A, 2)
    for k in 1:n
        A[k+1:n, k] ./= A[k,k]
    end
    A
end

A = rand(10000,10000)
B = copy(A)
@allocated test1(B) # returns 0
C = copy(A)
@allocated test2(C) # returns 401131136
C == B # returns true
```

Moreover I tried to eliminate syntactic sugar and wrote one more test function

```
function test3(A)
    n = size(A, 2)
    for k in 1:n
        broadcast!(/, A[k+1:n, k], A[k+1:n, k], A[k,k])
    end
    A
end
```

And this one allocates twice as much memory as `test2` and... returns wrong result.

Why does `test3` return wrong result, and what's wrong with broadcasting, are there any guides explaining how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break down what the syntax ends up meaning. This was your first broadcasting attempt and its equivalents (well, the steps in `Meta.@lower` are a bit different but it does the same thing for `Array`s):

```
A[k+1:n, k] ./= A[k,k]
A[k+1:n, k] .= A[k+1:n, k] ./ A[k,k]
broadcast!(/, @view(A[k+1:n, k]), A[k+1:n, k], A[k,k])
```

Note how `.=` `broadcast!` is set up to write the results to a *view* of the left-hand side array `A`. A view accesses the memory of an array, and it is non-allocating as of v1.5. Your second attempt with `broadcast!` missed this detail, so you ended up writing to a new array instead of to `A`.

The issue is that slicing bracket syntax, such as `A[k+1:n, k]`, does `getindex`. If `getindex` is accessing >1 value, it allocates a new array and copies values to it, so in such cases, you want to use `view` instead of `getindex`. Here are the equivalent ways of doing that:

```
broadcast!(/, @view(A[k+1:n, k]), @view(A[k+1:n, k]), A[k,k])
A[k+1:n, k] .= @view(A[k+1:n, k]) ./ A[k,k]

@view(A[k+1:n, k]) ./= A[k,k]
@views A[k+1:n, k] ./= A[k,k]
```

The `@view` macro allows you to use the slicing bracket syntax to call `view` instead of `getindex`.  The `@views` macro is a way to turn all slicing bracket syntax in the following expression to use `view` instead of `getindex`.

Comment: It should be noted that you have to expand the ./= to avoid all extra allocations.

The discussion of `@view` and `@views` in this answer is excellent, however.

Comment: Could you explain "expand the `./=`" in more detail, maybe with a line of code? I'm not sure what you mean by that and how it reduces allocation.

Comment: This statement is a bit imprecise: "If `getindex` is accessing >1 value, it allocates a new array". It's the _type_ of the indices that matter, a scalar index returns a scalar, an array index allocates an array. Even a single-element vector index will allocate.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that in `A[k+1:n, k] ./= A[k,k]` you can think of as it being rewritten as:

```
A[k+1:n, k] .= A[k+1:n, k] ./ A[k,k]
```

Now the point is that in the `A[k+1:n, k] ./ A[k,k]` part the `A[k+1:n, k]` part makes a copy of the array before division is performed. The reason is safety. You can override it by explicitly making a view instead of a copy:

```
function test2_fix(A)
    n = size(A, 2)
    for k in 1:n
        A[k+1:n, k] .= view(A, k+1:n, k) ./ A[k,k]
    end
    A
end
```

The `broadcast!` call is even worse and incorrect, because `A[k+1:n, k]` creates a copy twice (as you use it twice) before passing the values to `broadcast!` so your source array `A` will not be affected